# How to include file in doT.js templating system

Tags: javascript, templates, dot.js

I use doT.js 1.0 for templating with requirejs.
My goal is to load a file called "length.html" from another file called "freight.html".

The [advanced sample](https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/master/examples/advancedsnippet.txt) states that you can load files with

`{{#def.loadfile('/snippet.txt')}}`

So I tried using `{{#def.loadfile('/length.html')}}` in freight.html.
freight.html is in the same directory as length.html.

However, the javascript console throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loadfile'
```

How can I get loadfile to work? Or is the documentation wrong and there is no loadfile function?

Comment: Also, I found out that the advanced sample defines their own loadfile function elsewhere. But this seems to be for node.js because they use `var doT = require('doT');`
Do I have to define my own function?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though `loadfile` needs to be created by you, as per your requirements. If you are using express, I would suggest looking at https://github.com/nerdo/dot-emc. This module wraps doT so that you can use `res.render()` to return your templates. It also provides a nifty include function to solve the problem you have above. So instead of loadfile you would use:

`{{#def.include('length')}}`

Just be aware that if you use this module, the default file extension is `.def`, which needs to be changed with options to use say `.html`

Comment: I use the normal doT.js on the client side with a require-js plugin.